# How to run code before/after cucumber suite?

Tags: scala, cucumber

I'm trying to figure out how to run some code before and after all my cucumber tests run.

I've been tracking down a bug for a few days where some our processes create jobs on a server, and don't properly clean it up.  It's easy to miss so ideally I don't want engineers to have to manually add a check to every test.

I was hoping there'd be a way to put a hook in before any tests ran to cache how many jobs exist on the server, then a hook at the end to ensure that the value hasn't changed.

I know this isn't really the best way to use cucumber, as that is more of a system test type thing to do, but doing it this way would be the best way to fit it into the existing infrastructure.

Comment: are your tests running against a test server? If so why would it be a problem if jobs were created. Also how are the jobs being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using tagged hooks.

```
@Before("@jobCheck")
public void beforeScenario() {
  // actions
}

@After("@jobCheck")
public void afterScenario() {
  // actions
}
```

And then for each scenario that requires this check, add @jobCheck before the Scenario definition as below.

```
Feature: Some feature description
  @jobCheck
  Scenario: It should process a sentence
    // The steps
```

More on JVM hooks here: https://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

Use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations in your run file.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
    format = {"json", "<the report file>"},
    features = {"<the feature file>"},
    strict = false,
    glue = {"<package with steps classes>"})
public class TestRunFile { 
    @BeforeClass
    public static void getJobNumbersOnServerBeforeStarting() {
        //Implement logic
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void getJobNumbersOnServerAfterCompletion() {
        //Implement logic
    }
}
```